# onMouseOver: Prevent default behavior on desktop while keeping it on phone

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onmouseover

I am using onMouseOver, to detect when user taps on an image when accessing my web app on his phone:

```
  <img
            
                  onMouseOver={(e) => {
                    myImageWidget.open();
                  }}
                />
```

When he taps on the image, a widget appears and gets to upload an image.
The problem with using `onMouseOver` is that when the web app is used on desktop browser, the widget appears everytime the user mouse hovers on the image.
So is there a way to prevent that behavior on the desktop browser, while keeping the behavior on the phone?

Comment: try detecting screen size and then prevent default?

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using `onMouseOver` to mimic an `onClick` event. They are different for a reason. Why not just use `onClick` for both mobile **and** desktop? Secondly, there's no consistent and reliable way to distinguish between mobile and desktop outside of screen size, which obviously isn't always appropriate.

Comment: @Jayce444 onClick didn't work.

Comment: @sandeepjoshi screenSize isn't a reliable indicator.

Comment: There's no reason `onClick` shouldn't work on the `<img />` tag. How did it "not work". Didn't fire? Threw an error?

Comment: On the desktop, it opens the widget. On the phone, nothing happens

Comment: @Jayce444 For some reason, onClick started working

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to rely on the browser's User-Agent string, you can use [is-mobile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-mobile). NB: It seems not possible to reliably detect touch screens, cf [this thorough article.](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/)

```
import mobile from "is-mobile";

const isMobile = mobile(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor);

<img
  onMouseOver={(e) => {
    isMobile && myImageWidget.open();
  }}
/>
```